# How can I find the difference between two datasets in R?

Tags: r

I have two datasets, dataset A is contained within dataset B.
I want to select everything in B that isn't in A.
It seems like a really basic operation, but I wasn't able to find much on it by searching online.

Thanks in advance :)

example:

**A**
Key 1, 2, 3, 4

**B**
Key 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

**C (desired output)**
Key 5, 6, 7, 8

Comment: `dplyr::anti_join(B, A, by = 'key')` if a dataframe, else `setdiff(B, A)` if vectors

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `merge` from base R. (Note I modified B so that the example shows what happens when some of A is not in B):

```
Adf = data.frame(key=1:4, inA=T)
Bdf = data.frame(key=3:8, inB=T)
merge(Adf,Bdf,by='key', all=T)
```

Note the `all=T` which returns all rows from A and B, rather than just the inner join if `all=F`. This results in

```
  key  inA  inB
1   1 TRUE   NA
2   2 TRUE   NA
3   3 TRUE TRUE
4   4 TRUE TRUE
5   5   NA TRUE
6   6   NA TRUE
7   7   NA TRUE
8   8   NA TRUE
```

and you can filter rows accordingly.